# How to test overriden function with mocks

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I have the following contract

```js
contract TimeHelpers {
   function getTimestamp() internal virtual view {
       return block.timestamp;
   }
}
```

I have the contract that inherits from this

```js
contract ConcreteImpl is TimeHelpers {

    function start() public {
       uint timestamp = getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

Now, I wanna test `start` function(of course, it contains other logic as well, just not including). While testing it, I need to mock `getTimestamp()` so that it returns what I want.

**Way 1. I can write `ConreteImplMock` such as**

```js
contract ConcreteImplMock is ConreteImp {

    function getTimestamp() internal override returns(uint) {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Problem with this way is that wherever I use `TimeHelpers`, in that contract, I should be adding the overriden `getTimestamp` which I don't like.

**Way 2. I can write `TimeHelpersMock` that inherits from `TimeHelpers`.**

```js
contract TimeHelpersLock is TimeHelpers {

    function getTimestamp() internal override returns(uint) {
       return 100;
    }
}

contract ConcreteImplMock is ConcreteImpl, TimeHelpersMock {
    
    
}
```

Now, problem is that in the final inheritance chain, `getTimestamp` ends up to be in 2 base classes and I get the following error:

> Derived contract must override function "getTimestamp". Two or more
> base classes define function with same name and parameter types.

**Question: How would you approach this ?**